# Find Expected value

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, descriptive-statistics, stationary-processes

Suppose, $X \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$, Then what is  $\operatorname{E}\left(\dfrac{1}{X+1}\right)$ ?

My attempt:

Let $Y = \dfrac{1}{X+1}.$ Then

$$
F_Y(t) = \{ Y \leq t\} = \left\{ X \geq \frac{1-t} t \right\} = 1- F_Y \left( \frac{1-t} t \right).
$$

is this way okay? Any hint/alternative way to solve this ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Substitute and compensate.

$$E\left[\frac{1}{1+X}\right] = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{1+k}.\frac{\lambda^ke^{-\lambda}}{k!}= \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\lambda^ke^{-\lambda}}{(k+1)!}$$

Can you take it from here or do you need more help?

Comment: Thank you so much, I got the answer, We can simplify $$\sum_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{(k+1)!} = \frac{e^{-\lambda}}{\lambda}  \left[   \left( 1 + \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^m}{m!} \right) -1   \right] = \frac{1-e^{-\lambda}}{\lambda}$$

Comment: That is correct. Glad to be of help :)